# Can I run two Simpy environments in parallel

Tags: python, redis, simpy

I would like to model two processes:

(1) A simple real-time message broadcaster (deterministic) and

(2) Another process which receives data externally in real-time (from a Redis db) and then compares its own message to the value of the last message broadcast by (1)

I have been playing around with Simpy and thought this could be done by creating two parallel environment instances and getting one to peer into the state of the other. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If both process exchange data, they must run within the same environment.  Since SimPy processes run asynchronously, this is no problem.

Comment: Process (1) basically reads down a predefined list containing (value, time_delta). I want this process to match the implied realtime pace as closely as possible. In process (2), I tried yielding: env.timeout(delay=0) to capture the update then revert immediately, unsuccessfully. How would you structure process (2) ?